# Bind Complex Type in Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, types, complextype

I have created a Complex Type called "EmployeeName" using the Entity Framework designer in VS 2010.
EmployeeName consists of FirstName,LastName & title.
Now question is how do i display/bind to datagrid in  silverlight?
Right now it is displayes in Datagrid as "Namespace.EmployeeName" in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to set AutoGenerateColumns to false on the DataGrid to avoid getting the default column type of DataGridTextColumn for all the properties of your bound objects.

You then need to define the columns in xaml for each of the properties of your bound objects that you want displayed. For properties with a simple type like `string` or `int` (for example) you can just use a `DataGridTextColumn` with a standard binding in the binding property.

For your complex type (`EmployeeName`) you need to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and then define a `DataTemplate` for the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` property which tells the column how to display an `EmployeeName`. A simple example which just uses a single `TextBlock` and a `Run` for each property of the `EmployeeName` would be as follows

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false">
     <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding EmployeeName.Title}"></Run>
                        <Run Text="{Binding EmployeeName.FirstName}"></Run>
                        <Run Text="{Binding EmployeeName.LastName}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: this assumes Silverlight 4 where the Text property of Run is a dependency property (thus bindable). If you aren't using 4 you could just stack 3 TextBlocks using a StackPanel oriented horizontally.

Comment: I think this is a bit of overkill.... but if OP says its fine then i will upvote your answer because its far more complete than mine XD

Comment: @Drknezz not sure what you mean by overkill. Only difference between your answer and mine is that mine uses a single grid column to display the name where yours would require 3.

Comment: DataTemplates arent really needed here as the elements can just be bound to their ToString()'s and thats pretty much it, but i guess both ways are totally viable. Also, having separate columns would be nicer if you ask me :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to create each column in XAML and set AutoGenerateColumns to false, as well as binding each column manually to the property you want to display using the Binding property of each column.

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

That site has more info in the subject. It is designed for WPF but it will work for Silverlight as well ;)

Good Luck and Enjoy programming.